# Random number generator in arbitrary probability distribution fashion

Tags: c, algorithm, random

[HERE](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/random-number-generator-in-arbitrary-probability-distribution-fashion/) is the geeksforgeeks solution. I am not able to understand the findCeil() part. 
Step 4. Find index of Ceil of random number generated in step #3 in the prefix array. Let the index be indexc.

```
// Utility function to find ceiling of r in arr[l..h]
int findCeil(int arr[], int r, int l, int h)
{
    int mid;
    while (l < h)
    {
         mid = l + ((h - l) >> 1);  // Same as mid = (l+h)/2
        (r > arr[mid]) ? (l = mid + 1) : (h = mid);
    }
    return (arr[l] >= r) ? l : -1;
}
```

Can someone please explain what is being done.

Comment: Is there something in particular you don't understand? Maybe the ">>" or the "?".  Without narrowing your query down, you're going to get answers like "first, it declares an integer with the name `mid`..." and you'll just get a restatement of what you've already read.

Comment: Sorry about this. I meant to ask what is the purpose of findCeil that is it. What is findCeil doing here. With an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's performing a [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) of the array to find the first element of the array with a value greater than r. The wiki article should explain the technique pretty well.

edit: [Here's an animation of an example search](http://video.franklin.edu/Franklin/Math/170/common/mod01/binarySearchAlg.html)

Comment: Hi Katie. Thanks. Are you too preparing for interviews and/or working ?

Comment: I have a lot of ten minute compiles going on today, so I've been spending too much time on here in between and just happened to see your question go by. But I don't think we're supposed to use this space for chatting. :-)